# Many medicine labels inform the user to store below 86°F

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, conventions, units

In our medicine labels, every time we see it warn us to keep the medicine under 86 degree Fahrenheit. Why?

Answer (score 2):

That is 30 degrees C, which is a nice round number.